# Compile Time Error on using CFSocketStream

Tags: ios, sockets, networking, bonjour, cfnetwork

The following line of code is causing compile errors in my iOS application

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToNetService(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFNetServiceRef)netService, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

If I replace the code with **CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost**, it is working fine.

The errors are given below;

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToNetService", referenced from:
  -[Connection connect] in Connection.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: `-framework CFNetwork`

Comment: Yeah, thank you H2CO3. I figured it out sometime ago. I had to add CFNetwork framework...

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution was to add CFNetwork framework to build phase. I missed it somehow.